# Delete item from HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript

I have something like:

```
var elChildren = element.children;
```

How can i delete some items from the end of elChildren? Is there something like splice for this type of list?

Answer (score 3):

Directly, you can't. As per the spec, an HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live, it's automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.
It only has the property `HTMLCollection.length` that's read-only and the methods `HTMLCollection.item()` and `HTMLCollection.namedItem()`. If you want to alter it, you will have to turn it into an array or an object.

Comment: more strictly, _copy_ it into an array

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making it an array and using splice from there.

Comment: @Alnitak Since copying is the only way to turn it into an array I hardly think there's any need to specify.

Comment: @Nit you know that, I figured the OP probably didn't.